# Formatting numbers in .bat files

Tags: windows, batch-file

In a .bat file, I echo strings containing large numerical data (representing bytes of a Storage Space, i.e. non-negative big integers), e.g.:

```
"   123456789012345"
```

I'd like to format these numbers for better readability, but unfortunately, I am not able to find any kind of Format function for use within .bat files.

My desired output would be:

```
"    123,456,789,012,345"
```

Is there an awkwardly named Format function I am not aware of? If not, is there a best practice function to format such numbers, possibly involving the For statement? (If neither, does no-one but me want to format numbers?)

Comment: No, there's no string formatting function in batch file but you can iterate using `for ... in ...` to insert thousand separators depending on number length.

Comment: you could use a third party program like sed, an approximation as a start would be `echo 123456789 | sed -r "s/[0-9]{3}/\0,/g"`  which produces `123,456,789,`  except the issue with that is besides the comma at the end, if the number of digits is not a multiple of 3 then it doesn't get it right.  It'd be doable, there are some batch experts around on this site that could do it even possibly without a third party program! And generally things marked as batch should be pure batch.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using a batch and not something more advanced like a PowerShell script? That would probably enable you to easily format those numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's no such function to format numeric strings in default batch file commands, but you can create a batch script to insert thousand separators like this:

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var1=%1"

echo Input: %var1%

rem Credit to Aacini (so/a/28704587)
set "var2="
set "sign="
if "%var1:~0,1%" equ "-" set "sign=-" & set "var1=%var1:~1%"

for /L %%i in (1,1,%2) do if defined var1 (
   set "var2=,!var1:~-3!!var2!"
   set "var1=!var1:~0,-3!"
)
set "var2=%sign%%var2:~1%

echo Output: %var2%
```

Usage:

```
[filename].bat [number] [grouping]

e.g. [filename].bat 12345678901234567890 5
```

Console output example:

```
Input: 123456789012345
Output: 123,456,789,012,345
```

NB: Use spaces after `echo` commands to add spaces in output number as many as you want.